# Single Variable Calculus Fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm quite lost on the following problem:

*The function $f(x)$ is:*

$$f(x)=\int_0^{g(x)} \frac {1}{1+\sin(t) + e^t} dt $$

*where $g(x)$ is*

$$g(x)=\int _{-x}^{x^2} h(t) \, dt $$

And $h(t)$ is odd such that $h(1) = 2$. Find the equation of the tangent line of $f(x)$ at $x=1$.

Please help.

Comment: Do you know in general how to compute the tangent line at a point?

Comment: Yes, I know that!

Comment: You seem to know that you need the FTC, so it appears this will ultimately involve you plugging in a certain function into another and computing a composition.

Comment: Hint: you just need to find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$. The former is easy because $h$ is odd, and the latter can be computed with help from Mhenni Benghorbal's answer.

Comment: Oh I see!! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the line tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=1$ we must find $f(1)$ and $f'(1)$.

Starting with $f(1)$:

$$f(1)=\int^{g(1)}_{0}\frac{1}{1+\sin t+e^t}dt$$

Proceeding to compute $g(1)$, we have

$$g(1)=\int^{1}_{-1}h(t)dt$$

Since we know that $h(t)$ is odd, we know that $-h(t)=h(-t)$, so any integral of $h$ symmetric to the origin will be $0$. Hence $g(1)=0$. Returning to $f(1)$ we see that

$$f(1)=\int^{0}_{0}\frac{1}{1+\sin t+e^t}dt=0$$

Now turning to $f'(1)$, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we have

$$f'(x)=\frac{g'(x)}{1+\sin g(x) + e^{g(x)}}$$

so

$$f'(1)=\frac{g'(1)}{1+\sin g(1) + e^{g(1)}}$$

Since we already know $g(1)$ it remains only to compute $g'(1)$. We see that

$$g'(x)=2x\cdot h(x^2)-(-1)\cdot h(-x)$$

by the FTC. Then, again remembering that $h$ is odd and that $h(1)=2$,

$$g'(1)=2\cdot h(1)+h(-1)=2\cdot2+(-2)=2$$

Having computed all the required values, we see that

$$f'(1)=\frac{2}{1+\sin 0 + e^{0}}=\frac{2}{2}=1$$

Now the tangent line to $f$ at $x=1$ is of the form $y-f(1)=f'(1)(x-1)$. Thus

$$y=x-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is your tool ([Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule))

> $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t) dt=f(h(x)) h'(x)-f(g(x))g'(x). $$

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested information.

Comment: @ZellAllon: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the antiderivative of $m=\frac{1}{1+\sin t+e^t}$, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$f(x)=\int_0^{g(x)}m(t)\,dt=F(g(x))-F(0)$, then the tangent line of $f$ is given by $f'$, so:

$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(F(g(x)-F(0))=g'(x)F'(g(x))$

$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(H(x^2)-H(-x))=2xh(x^2)+h(-x)$ ($H$ is the antiderivative of $h$)

so $f'(1)=g'(1)F'(g(1))=(2h(1)+h(-1))\large(\frac{1}{1+\sin(g(1))+e^{g(1)}})$

$=(2h(1)-h(1))(\frac{1}{1+\sin(g(1))+e^{g(1)}})=2(\frac{1}{1+\sin(g(1))+e^{g(1)}})$

Now $g(1)=\int_{-1}^1h(t)dt=0$ because $h$ is odd.

so $f'(1)=1$

Comment: Thank you for providing the requested information.